# I need help in phpmysql complicated queries

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have three table. The table name is

1. salary_history_table - employee_id(foreignkey)
2. employee_table - employee_id(primary) department_structure_id(foreign)
3. department_table - department_structure_id(primary)

Now the salary_history_table has an id called "employee_id" which is the primary key in employee_table. And the employee_table have an id called "department_structured_id" which is the primary key in department_table, my problem is i want to update all data in salary_history_table column called rate_exempt based on "department_structured_id" from the department_table. How can i join the three table and update all that is related to particular id query base on employee_id?

Comment: what have you tried? What would a sample data before and after look like? Edit the question to include these details.

Answer (score 1):

First, it’s helpful to draw out the tables and their relationships  (I’ve shortened names for the sake of typing on my phone)

```
salary_history  employee          department
employee_id —-> employee_id
rate_exempt     department_id ——> department_id
```

So, if you wanted to list the salary history of all employees of all departments,

```
select s.* 
from department d 
inner join employee e on e.department_id = d.department_id
inner join salary_history s on s.employee.id = e.employee.id
```

But for your question, you don’t even need to join all three tables if you know the department_id

```
select s.*
from salary_history s
inner join employee e on e.employee_id = s.employee_id
where e.department_id = ?
```

But if you don’t know the department id and you have to match based on, say, department name

```
select s.*
from salary_history s
inner join employee e on e.employee_id = s.employee_id
inner join department d on d.department_id = e.department_id
where d.name = ?
```

Using this, you can set up your update. The syntax appears to vary between db systems, so you’ll have to see which works for you

```
update salary s
inner join employee e on e.employee_id=s.employee_id
inner join department d on d.department_id=e.department_id
set rate_exempt = ?
where d.name=?

or,

update ...
set...
inner join
inner join
where

or,

update salary
set rate_exempt = ?
where employee_id in (
    select e.employee_id
    from employee e
    inner join department d on d.department_id=e.department_id
    where d.name = ?
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, not that complicated. Just use the below query, well let me tell you how it works, first, you have to call a table which has both values, here I'm calling it in `get()` once you got both Id's then you can join another table with these ids.

```
$this->db->join('salary_history_table', 'salary_history_table.employee_id = employee_table.employee_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('department_table', 'department_table.department_structure_id = employee_table.department_structure_id', 'left');
$this->db->get('employee_table');
```

Let me know if you still have any issues.